# How to get boxes true in a list of checkboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, for-loop, checkbox

I have to display a list of checkboxes (50) from a table A, in this list i have to mark as true boxes that are checked depending on elements in table B.
The goal is to have all the 50 checkboxes with those checked.
Can you guys help me please.

```
        int envid = int.Parse(txtenvid.Text);
        DataView oDvPop = PopulationBL.BigList();
        DataView listPop = PopulationBL.SmallListCheckeditems(envid, 1);
        CheckBoxList list = new CheckBoxList();
        CheckBox check;
        CheckBox check2;
        for (int i = 0; i < listPop.Count; i++)
        {
            check = new CheckBox();
            check2 = new CheckBox();              
            check.Text = listPop[i]["POP"].ToString();
            for (int j = 0; j < oDvPop.Count; j++)
            {
            check2.Text = oDvPop[j]["POP_LABEL"].ToString();
            if (check.Text == check2.Text)
                check.Checked = true;
                checkBoxes.Add(check);
            chkListPop.Controls.Add(check);
            }

        }
        chkListPop.Controls.Add(check);
```

Comment: Type of chkListPop :   <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkListPop" RepeatColumns="4">
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are doing

```
CheckBox check = new CheckBox();
CheckBox check2 = new CheckBox();
```

outside the loop so will have the last values assign in all of `checkboxes`. So insatiate it inside loop.

```
 CheckBox check;
 CheckBox check2;
 for (int i = 0; i < listPop.Count; i++)
 {
     check = new CheckBox();
     check2 = new CheckBox();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment you are right.

Comment: I think i miss something in this place :                                             
          checkBoxes.Add(check);
            chkListPop.Controls.Add(check);
            }

        }
        chkListPop.Controls.Add(check);
        chkListPop.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

Comment: शेखर can you please help me